# How to locate websocketbridge.js in Django using channels websocket?

Tags: django, python-3.x, websocket, redis, channel

I am trying to implement websockets using channels in Django project. I am getting 404 for webscoketbridge.js Below is html template.

    `{% load staticfiles %}`
    
    `{% block title %}`Delivery`{% endblock %}`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Satisfy' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="{% static 'channels/js/websocketbridge.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

[image]

[image]

Also, I tried to have a look in the virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/channels path, there is no js folder or any file named websocketbridge.js

Has anyone solved this issue?

Comment: Someone please help to resolve this... I've no clue :/

Answer (score 2):

The javascript bridge was removed in v2.1.4. Here's the commit: https://github.com/django/channels/commit/2a9d764ad03927581aa2bfcadccc3e953949cb98#diff-b582cbb2f8294afa8bbe26c4c360a01d

This bit me, in my book that breaks semantic versioning.

Answer (score 2):

As @tobyspark said, the javascript wrapper has been completely removed in the Django-channels 2. You can read more on how the js WebSocket wrapper was working in channels 1 [here](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/1.x/javascript.html).

the simplest workaround to clear that error in your browser is to create a file called websocketbridge.js in the path shown in the error, "static/channels/js/", or you can specify any other path in your HTML  src attribute matching the location of the static files and then add the code from [here](https://github.com/django/channels/blob/2.1.3/channels/static/channels/js/websocketbridge.js).

But you have to find a better implementation. You can use ReconnectingWebSocket. In the channels 2 release documentation, it is stated there might be other third-party packages for the binding but I don't know any other.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will surely have a check on this