# django-channels websocket bridge error when trying to connect web socket

Tags: python, django, django-channels

Im trying to implement real time notifications in my django app.I have set up signals and consumers . Im getting an error in the javascript side

My javascript code:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  const webSocketBridge = new channels.WebSocketBridge();

  const nl = document.querySelector("#nl");

  webSocketBridge.connect('student/dashboard/tasks/');

  webSocketBridge.listen(function(action, stream) {
    console.log("RESPONSE:", action);


    if(action.event == "New Task") {
      var el = document.createElement("li");
      el.innerHTML = ` <b>${action.username}</b> completed Task 
     ${action.title}`;

      nl.appendChild(el);
    }

  })

  document.ws = webSocketBridge; /* for debugging */


})
</script>
```

The error shows on the console :

```
  TypeError: Invalid WebSocket constructor. Set 
  `options.constructor
```

Comment: are you using channels v2? the WebSocketBridge is not supported for this version of channels.

Comment: Figured it ..I switched it with ReconnectingWebSocket   @MatthausWoolard

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to locate websocketbridge.js in Django using channels websocket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53468845/how-to-locate-websocketbridge-js-in-django-using-channels-websocket)