# How to process messages with django-channels 2?

Tags: javascript, django, django-channels

Within my Django project, I created a notification app that detect whenever a specific model is saved and push a notification to all clients (based on 
https://arunrocks.com/understanding-django-channels/ and
https://github.com/arocks/channels-example
). I have updated my code to Channels 2 and I have now an issue with the javascript wrapper which has been removed in the django-channels 2([How to locate websocketbridge.js in Django using channels websocket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53468845/how-to-locate-websocketbridge-js-in-django-using-channels-websocket))

Before I had a script that processes messages:

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const webSocketBridge = new channels.WebSocketBridge();
    const nl = document.querySelector("#notifylist");

    webSocketBridge.connect('/notifications/');
    webSocketBridge.listen(function(action, stream) {
      console.log("RESPONSE:", action);
      if(action.event == "New User") {
        var el = document.createElement("li");
        el.innerHTML = action.text;
        nl.appendChild(el);
      }
    })
  })
</script>
```

This script doesn't work anymore. They suggested to replace WebSocketBridge.js by ReconnectingWebSocket.js but I don't know how I can adapt my previous script in order to use ReconnectingWebSocket.js.

Has anyone updated his/her code by using ReconnectingWebSocket? If so, could you, please, provide an example.

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few features of the old wrapper that are no longer directly supported in channels v2

namely the concept of `stream` and `action`.

you can either do this yourself (within your consumer and js code).

or there is a lib (disclaimer I am the author) https://github.com/hishnash/djangochannelsrestframework that when combined with https://github.com/hishnash/channelsmultiplexer provides the `action` + `stream` concepts from channelsV1

you can also use this js lib https://github.com/theY4Kman/dcrf-client alongside it.

Comment: Thank you Matthaus for your comment. I looked at your lib but to be honest, I didn't see how your library can replace easily the javascript part. Could you please provide an example?